# Drupal 7x Omega 4 bundle install fails

Tags: ruby, drupal, rubygems, bundle

I have created a omega subtheme with drush omega-wizard. Trying to fire up omega guard with drush omega-guard gives me this:

> There was a problem with your setup:
>   [error] Resolving dependencies... Bundler can't satisfy your Gemfile's
>   dependencies. Install missing gems with `bundle install`.

Running bundle install resolves the first couple of dependencies - addressable, sass, sass-maps, breakpoint and the it fails with the following message:

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> /Users/brix/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby extconf.rb  creating Makefile
> ```
>
> make  clean
>
> make compiling hitimes.c make: *** [hitimes.o] Segmentation fault: 11
>
> make failed, exit code 2
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Users/brix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@omega.haandvaerk/gems/hitimes-1.2.2
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /Users/brix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@omega.haandvaerk/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/1.9.1/hitimes-1.2.2/gem_make.out
>   An error occurred while installing hitimes (1.2.2), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that `gem install hitimes -v '1.2.2'` succeeds
>   before bundling.

I am on OS X Yosemite - 10.10.1

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on Ubuntu 14.04, and I was not able to install hitimes, but I found out some shell problems with gnome or sth, with solution [here](https://groups.drupal.org/node/444418#comment-1062493)
. I don't know anything about mac, but I hope my experience become a light in finding your path :D